# Start two X servers on boot on RHEL

Tags: xorg, gdm, startx, multiseat

I have a powerful machine that I want to use as a multi-seat system. It has two graphic cards and two pairs of keyboards and mice. I've been able to successfully configure two "seats" using udev and Xorg.conf, and launch two X servers from a script so two users can have independent sessions. Just for the record, here's my udev rules file, where I identify each USB hub and label the devices and the seats:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", KERNEL=="card[0-9]*", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x10de", DRIVERS=="nvidia", TAG+="master-of-seat"
# SUBSYSTEM=="drm", KERNEL=="card0", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat0"
# SUBSYSTEM=="drm", KERNEL=="card1", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat1"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_default"

# KVM HUBS
KERNELS=="3-2", ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09", ENV{KVM_HUB}="1", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat0"
KERNELS=="3-8", ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09", ENV{KVM_HUB}="2", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat1"

# Devices of HUB 1
KERNEL=="event*", ENV{KVM_HUB}=="1", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01" SYMLINK+="kvm_keyboard_1"
KERNEL=="event*", ENV{KVM_HUB}=="1", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02" SYMLINK+="kvm_mouse_1"

# Devices of HUB 2
KERNEL=="event*", ENV{KVM_HUB}=="2", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01" SYMLINK+="kvm_keyboard_2"
KERNEL=="event*", ENV{KVM_HUB}=="2", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02" SYMLINK+="kvm_mouse_2"

# Default seat
SUBSYSTEM=="input", TAG=="seat", ENV{ID_SEAT}=="" , ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat0"

# set all tags accordingly
ENV{ID_SEAT}!="", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}+="$env{ID_SEAT}" TAG+="$env{ID_SEAT}"
```

The relevant part of my `xorg.conf` file looks like this:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    # Option         "AutoAddDevices"      "false"
    # Option         "AutoEnableDevices"   "false"
    Option         "DefaultServerLayout" "Layout0"
    Option         "AllowMouseOpenFail"  "true"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection


# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# LAYOUT

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen         "Screen0"
    MatchSeat      "seat0"
    Option         "Clone"   "off"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout1"
    Screen         "Screen1"
    MatchSeat      "seat1"
    Option         "Clone"   "off"
EndSection
```

As I said, **I can successfully launch** two independent sessions using the following script, but I'd like this to happen automatically on boot.

```
#!/bin/bash
set +x

rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
cp ./xorg_independientes /etc/X11/xorg.conf

# X (:0)
systemctl stop gdm
killall Xorg
killall X
systemctl restart gdm

sleep 7

# X (:1)
su - sit -c "startx /usr/bin/gnome-session -- :1 vt4 -layout Layout1 -seat seat1 -sharevts" &
sleep 10
DISPLAY=:1 xhost +
```

My approach would be setting the default target runlevel to 4 (so it has everything but graphics) and then placing these commands in a script somewhere.

Comment: The usual place to start multiple X servers would be in the display manager (after all, that's the program responsible for start the X server). I'm using xdm, where `/etc/X11/xdm/Xservers` would be the file to edit, but I don't know how gdm does it.

Comment: I'll eventually be using no display managers, just bare X servers.

Comment: Then I'd first try to do it without the display manager (deinstall it). `X` has options `-config` and `-configdir` if you want different config files. I'd guess you'd be able to start them as systemd services, under some target that corresponds to runlevel 4 (if you want to keep systemd).

Comment: You might check out the `loginctl` command for systemd. It talks a lot about seats, though I don't know the details.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in RHEL6, they use Upstart for starting processes at boot. In order to start two different X servers, create 2 separate scripts to start your X server on :0 and :1.

`start_colon_0.sh:`

```
#!/bin/sh
su - sit -c "startx -- :0 vt4 -layout Layout0 -seat seat0 -sharevts" &
```

`start_colon_1.sh:`

```
#!/bin/sh
su - sit -c "startx -- :1 vt4 -layout Layout1 -seat seat1 -sharevts" &
```

In `/etc/init`, create 2 configuration files as follows:

`x_server_0.conf:`

```
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=5
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[!5]
console output
respawn
exec start_colon_0.sh
```

`x_server_1.conf:`

```
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=5
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[!5]
console output
respawn
exec start_colon_1.sh
```

This will run your scripts at startup when entering runlevel 5.

See the [Upstart tutorial](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html/)